# Draw bitmap and save/share it

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to use an existing drawable and add some other Bitmaps as well as text to finally use it as sharing intent. 
My actually code works, but only a few apps can open the saved image. using it as mail attachment or with a messenger only shows a black screen or cannnot open it anyway.

```
            Bitmap bitmap =  ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("drawable://" + R.drawable.my_image);
            android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
            if(bitmapConfig == null) 
            {
              bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            }
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);   
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
            paint.setTextSize((int) (10));
            paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

            canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("drawable://" + R.drawable.image1), canvas.getWidth() - 100, 10, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("drawable://" + R.drawable.image2), canvas.getWidth() - 50, 10, paint);

            canvas.drawText("TEST", 100, 10, paint);            
            canvas.drawText("TEST1", 10, canvas.getHeight() - 10, paint);   
            canvas.drawText("TEST2", 10 + (canvas.getWidth() / 2), canvas.getHeight() - 10, paint);
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "TESTIMAGE_" + counter + ".png");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
            shareIntent.setType("image/png");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));
        } 
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {


        }
```

Is there any mistake while processing or sharing which I have to solve, to use image as expected?

Comment: Just glancing at your code and I think the issue is that you are saving the image to your app's private directory where other apps cannot read. Try changing getFilesDir() to Environment.getExternalStorageDir()

Comment: I still got black background instead of the image I thought to get, but the main struggle not to see the image as mailattachment is solved, that was too easy :-) Please add this comment as answer to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attachment is not readable by other apps because you are saving it to `getFilesDir()`.

Simply change `getFilesDir()` to `Environment.getExternalStorageDir()` and other apps will be able to handle the saved image. This also requires you to add the following permission in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't know why the image is black, I would have to see the resources. Best of luck.

Comment: I solved my "black image" problem too, now its done :-) thanks alot